# iPhone Taskbar close all applications

Tags: iphone, windows

Is there a way to close all application in the taskbar at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### No.

You have to manually remove each one.

Answer (score 0):

One nifty trick I learned from a friend: Enter "wiggle" mode for the taskbar, then tap the icons **from right to left**. This way you can close at least four apps in a steady motion without having to wait for the icons move one column to the right. Sounds obvious, but try it out and you’ll see what I mean.